# CEF - Render process methods such as OnContextCreated not being called

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, chromium, chromium-embedded

Long time lurker, but happy to be here. I'm attempting to bind a basic javascript binding to the cefSimple application.

I'm working on an up-to-date Macbook as well as an up-to-date iMac.

Numerous searches have resulted in some basic mistakes I was making- but I seem to have rectified them all and it still work go.

Specifically, I have made certain to have my SimpleApp class inherit from CefRenderProcessHandler (atleast, I think it's inheriting. The syntax is still a bit new to new)

I have also envoked GetRenderProcessHandler in that class aswell.

The other main suggestion I've seen is to be sure to pass the SimpleApp instance to CefExecuteProcess- which I have done.

Here is my code:

simple_app.mm

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors.
// Portions copyright (c) 2010 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#include "include/cef_application_mac.h"
#include "include/wrapper/cef_helpers.h"
#include "include/wrapper/cef_library_loader.h"
#include "tests/cefsimple/simple_app.h"
#include "tests/cefsimple/simple_handler.h"

// Receives notifications from the application.
@interface SimpleAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
- (void)createApplication:(id)object;
- (void)tryToTerminateApplication:(NSApplication*)app;
@end

// Provide the CefAppProtocol implementation required by CEF.
@interface SimpleApplication : NSApplication <CefAppProtocol> {
 @private
  BOOL handlingSendEvent_;
}
@end

@implementation SimpleApplication
- (BOOL)isHandlingSendEvent {
  return handlingSendEvent_;
}

- (void)setHandlingSendEvent:(BOOL)handlingSendEvent {
  handlingSendEvent_ = handlingSendEvent;
}

- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent*)event {
  CefScopedSendingEvent sendingEventScoper;
  [super sendEvent:event];
}

// |-terminate:| is the entry point for orderly "quit" operations in Cocoa. This
// includes the application menu's quit menu item and keyboard equivalent, the
// application's dock icon menu's quit menu item, "quit" (not "force quit") in
// the Activity Monitor, and quits triggered by user logout and system restart
// and shutdown.
//
// The default |-terminate:| implementation ends the process by calling exit(),
// and thus never leaves the main run loop. This is unsuitable for Chromium
// since Chromium depends on leaving the main run loop to perform an orderly
// shutdown. We support the normal |-terminate:| interface by overriding the
// default implementation. Our implementation, which is very specific to the
// needs of Chromium, works by asking the application delegate to terminate
// using its |-tryToTerminateApplication:| method.
//
// |-tryToTerminateApplication:| differs from the standard
// |-applicationShouldTerminate:| in that no special event loop is run in the
// case that immediate termination is not possible (e.g., if dialog boxes
// allowing the user to cancel have to be shown). Instead, this method tries to
// close all browsers by calling CloseBrowser(false) via
// ClientHandler::CloseAllBrowsers. Calling CloseBrowser will result in a call
// to ClientHandler::DoClose and execution of |-performClose:| on the NSWindow.
// DoClose sets a flag that is used to differentiate between new close events
// (e.g., user clicked the window close button) and in-progress close events
// (e.g., user approved the close window dialog). The NSWindowDelegate
// |-windowShouldClose:| method checks this flag and either calls
// CloseBrowser(false) in the case of a new close event or destructs the
// NSWindow in the case of an in-progress close event.
// ClientHandler::OnBeforeClose will be called after the CEF NSView hosted in
// the NSWindow is dealloc'ed.
//
// After the final browser window has closed ClientHandler::OnBeforeClose will
// begin actual tear-down of the application by calling CefQuitMessageLoop.
// This ends the NSApplication event loop and execution then returns to the
// main() function for cleanup before application termination.
//
// The standard |-applicationShouldTerminate:| is not supported, and code paths
// leading to it must be redirected.
- (void)terminate:(id)sender {
  SimpleAppDelegate* delegate =
      static_cast<SimpleAppDelegate*>([NSApp delegate]);
  [delegate tryToTerminateApplication:self];
  // Return, don't exit. The application is responsible for exiting on its own.
}
@end

@implementation SimpleAppDelegate

// Create the application on the UI thread.
- (void)createApplication:(id)object {
  [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainMenu"
                                owner:NSApp
                      topLevelObjects:nil];

  // Set the delegate for application events.
  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)tryToTerminateApplication:(NSApplication*)app {
  SimpleHandler* handler = SimpleHandler::GetInstance();
  if (handler && !handler->IsClosing())
    handler->CloseAllBrowsers(false);
}

- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:
    (NSApplication*)sender {
  return NSTerminateNow;
}
@end

// Entry point function for the browser process.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Load the CEF framework library at runtime instead of linking directly
  // as required by the macOS sandbox implementation.
  CefScopedLibraryLoader library_loader;
  if (!library_loader.LoadInMain())
    return 1;

  // Provide CEF with command-line arguments.
  CefMainArgs main_args(argc, argv);

  @autoreleasepool {
    // Initialize the SimpleApplication instance.
    [SimpleApplication sharedApplication];

    // Specify CEF global settings here.
    CefSettings settings;

    // When generating projects with CMake the CEF_USE_SANDBOX value will be
    // defined automatically. Pass -DUSE_SANDBOX=OFF to the CMake command-line
    // to disable use of the sandbox.
#if !defined(CEF_USE_SANDBOX)
    settings.no_sandbox = true;
#endif

    // SimpleApp implements application-level callbacks for the browser process.
    // It will create the first browser instance in OnContextInitialized() after
    // CEF has initialized.
    CefRefPtr<SimpleApp> app(new SimpleApp);

    // CEF applications have multiple sub-processes (render, plugin, GPU, etc)
    // that share the same executable. This function checks the command-line and,
    // if this is a sub-process, executes the appropriate logic.
    CefExecuteProcess(main_args, app, nullptr);

    // Initialize CEF for the browser process.
    CefInitialize(main_args, settings, app.get(), NULL);

    // Create the application delegate.
    NSObject* delegate = [[SimpleAppDelegate alloc] init];
    [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createApplication:)
                               withObject:nil
                            waitUntilDone:NO];

    // Run the CEF message loop. This will block until CefQuitMessageLoop() is
    // called.
    CefRunMessageLoop();

    // Shut down CEF.
    CefShutdown();

    // Release the delegate.
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [delegate release];
#endif  // !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    delegate = nil;
  }  // @autoreleasepool

  return 0;
}
```

simple_app.h

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
// can be found in the LICENSE file.

#ifndef CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_APP_H_
#define CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_APP_H_

#include "include/cef_app.h"

// Implement application-level callbacks for the browser process.
class SimpleApp : public CefApp, 
                                public CefBrowserProcessHandler,
                                public CefRenderProcessHandler {
 public:
  SimpleApp();

  // CefApp methods:
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefBrowserProcessHandler> GetBrowserProcessHandler()
      OVERRIDE {
    return this;
  }

  virtual CefRefPtr<CefRenderProcessHandler> GetRenderProcessHandler()
      OVERRIDE {
    return this;
  }

  // CefBrowserProcessHandler methods:
  virtual void OnContextInitialized() OVERRIDE;

  virtual void OnContextCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context) OVERRIDE;

 private:
  // Include the default reference counting implementation.
  IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(SimpleApp);
};

#endif  // CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_SIMPLE_APP_H_
```

simple_app.cc

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
// can be found in the LICENSE file.

#include "tests/cefsimple/simple_app.h"

#include <string>

#include "include/cef_browser.h"
#include "include/cef_command_line.h"
#include "include/views/cef_browser_view.h"
#include "include/views/cef_window.h"
#include "include/wrapper/cef_helpers.h"
#include "tests/cefsimple/simple_handler.h"

namespace {

// When using the Views framework this object provides the delegate
// implementation for the CefWindow that hosts the Views-based browser.
class SimpleWindowDelegate : public CefWindowDelegate {
 public:
  explicit SimpleWindowDelegate(CefRefPtr<CefBrowserView> browser_view)
      : browser_view_(browser_view) {}

  void OnWindowCreated(CefRefPtr<CefWindow> window) OVERRIDE {
    // Add the browser view and show the window.
    window->AddChildView(browser_view_);
    window->Show();

    // Give keyboard focus to the browser view.
    browser_view_->RequestFocus();
  }

  void OnWindowDestroyed(CefRefPtr<CefWindow> window) OVERRIDE {
    browser_view_ = NULL;
  }

  bool CanClose(CefRefPtr<CefWindow> window) OVERRIDE {
    // Allow the window to close if the browser says it's OK.
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser = browser_view_->GetBrowser();
    if (browser)
      return browser->GetHost()->TryCloseBrowser();
    return true;
  }

  CefSize GetPreferredSize(CefRefPtr<CefView> view) OVERRIDE {
    return CefSize(800, 600);
  }

 private:
  CefRefPtr<CefBrowserView> browser_view_;

  IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(SimpleWindowDelegate);
  DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(SimpleWindowDelegate);
};

}  // namespace

SimpleApp::SimpleApp() {}

void SimpleApp::OnContextInitialized() {
  CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

  CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line =
      CefCommandLine::GetGlobalCommandLine();

#if defined(OS_WIN) || defined(OS_LINUX)
  // Create the browser using the Views framework if "--use-views" is specified
  // via the command-line. Otherwise, create the browser using the native
  // platform framework. The Views framework is currently only supported on
  // Windows and Linux.
  const bool use_views = command_line->HasSwitch("use-views");
#else
  const bool use_views = false;
#endif

  // SimpleHandler implements browser-level callbacks.
  CefRefPtr<SimpleHandler> handler(new SimpleHandler(use_views));

  // Specify CEF browser settings here.
  CefBrowserSettings browser_settings;

  std::string url;

  // Check if a "--url=" value was provided via the command-line. If so, use
  // that instead of the default URL.
  url = command_line->GetSwitchValue("url");
  if (url.empty())
    url = "http://www.google.com";

  if (use_views) {
    // Create the BrowserView.
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowserView> browser_view = CefBrowserView::CreateBrowserView(
        handler, url, browser_settings, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the Window. It will show itself after creation.
    CefWindow::CreateTopLevelWindow(new SimpleWindowDelegate(browser_view));
  } else {
    // Information used when creating the native window.
    CefWindowInfo window_info;

#if defined(OS_WIN)
    // On Windows we need to specify certain flags that will be passed to
    // CreateWindowEx().
    window_info.SetAsPopup(NULL, "cefsimple");
#endif

    // Create the first browser window.
    CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(window_info, handler, url, browser_settings,
                                  NULL, NULL);
  }
}

void SimpleApp::OnContextCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
        CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
        CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context) {

  // Retrieve the context's window object.
   CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object = context->GetGlobal();

   // Create a new V8 string value. See the "Basic JS Types" section below.
   CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> str = CefV8Value::CreateString("My Value!");

   // Add the string to the window object as "window.myval". See the "JS Objects" section below.
   object->SetValue("myval", str, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);

}
```

And of course, the HTML to check if it's working.

CEFTest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <span id="thespan"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function SetValue(argument) {
            document.getElementById( 'thespan' ).innerHTML = window.myval + 'hello'
        }

        window.addEventListener( 'load', SetValue )

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My understanding of Cef is only just now starting to really take shape. What it looks like I've had to do is pass CefRenderProcessHandler to the SimpleApp class in order to allow it access to all of the RenderProcessHandler's methods. Then I had to override OnContextCreated with my own version (as the original version is simply a placeholder function)

Calling CefExecuteProcess serves, I think, to actually force the process to start. I could use some clarification on that.

Answer (score 1):

**What follows is a working version of CefSimple modified to include Javascript integration.**

So it turns out the problem stems from using a Mac instead of a Linux or PC machine

The code posted in my original post SHOULD work on a PC. I can't test it though because I don't have one. (If some kind soul wouldn't mind doing so, and posting the results, I'd appreciate it)

On a mac, render processes have a separate entry-point. In the case of CEFSimple this is the process_helper_mac.cc file. All that is needed is to create a class which extends CefRenderProcessHandler, override it's GetRenderProcessHandler method to return itself, and then wrap the subprocess in that class before sending it through to CefExecuteProcess.

In order to do this you need to define this new class, which I've called Helper_App, in a helper_app.h and helper_app.cc file. Lastly, you need to go in to the CMakeLists.txt file and actually instruct the build program to include the files we've written.

**TL;DR Create the helper_app.h and helper_app.cc files and paste in the following code. Modify the process_helper_mac.cc file as follows. Modify the CMakeLists.txt file as follows.**

helper_app.h

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. 

All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
// can be found in the LICENSE file.

#ifndef CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_HELPER_APP_H_
#define CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_HELPER_APP_H_

#include "include/cef_app.h"

// Implement application-level callbacks for the browser process.
class HelperApp : public CefApp, public CefRenderProcessHandler {
 public:
  HelperApp();

  // CefApp methods:
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefRenderProcessHandler> GetRenderProcessHandler()
      OVERRIDE {
    return this;
  }

  // CefBrowserProcessHandler methods:
  virtual void OnContextCreated( CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context ) OVERRIDE;

 private:
  // Include the default reference counting implementation.
  IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(HelperApp);
};

#endif  // CEF_TESTS_CEFSIMPLE_HELPER_APP_H_
```

helper_app.cc

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
// can be found in the LICENSE file.

#include "tests/cefsimple/helper_app.h"

HelperApp::HelperApp() {}

void HelperApp::OnContextCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
        CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
        CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context) {

  // Retrieve the context's window object.
   CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object = context->GetGlobal();

   // Create a new V8 string value. See the "Basic JS Types" section below.
   CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> str = CefV8Value::CreateString("My Value!");

   // Add the string to the window object as "window.myval". See the "JS Objects" section below.
   object->SetValue("myval", str, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);

}
```

process_helper_mac.cc

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
// reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can
// be found in the LICENSE file.

#include "include/cef_app.h"
#include "include/wrapper/cef_library_loader.h"

#include "tests/cefsimple/helper_app.h"

// When generating projects with CMake the CEF_USE_SANDBOX value will be defined
// automatically. Pass -DUSE_SANDBOX=OFF to the CMake command-line to disable
// use of the sandbox.
#if defined(CEF_USE_SANDBOX)
#include "include/cef_sandbox_mac.h"
#endif

// Entry point function for sub-processes.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
#if defined(CEF_USE_SANDBOX)
  // Initialize the macOS sandbox for this helper process.
  CefScopedSandboxContext sandbox_context;
  if (!sandbox_context.Initialize(argc, argv))
    return 1;
#endif

  // Load the CEF framework library at runtime instead of linking directly
  // as required by the macOS sandbox implementation.
  CefScopedLibraryLoader library_loader;
  if (!library_loader.LoadInHelper())
    return 1;

  // Provide CEF with command-line arguments.
  CefMainArgs main_args(argc, argv);

  CefRefPtr<HelperApp> app(new HelperApp);  // <--- Create an object of the type HelperApp

  // Execute the sub-process.
  return CefExecuteProcess(main_args, app, NULL); <--- Feed our HelperApp object through to CefExecuteProcess
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
# Copyright (c) 2014 The Chromium Embedded Framework Authors. All rights
# reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
# can be found in the LICENSE file.

#
# Source files.
#

# cefsimple sources.
set(CEFSIMPLE_SRCS
  simple_app.cc
  simple_app.h
  simple_handler.cc
  simple_handler.h
  )
set(CEFSIMPLE_SRCS_LINUX
  cefsimple_linux.cc
  simple_handler_linux.cc
  )
set(CEFSIMPLE_SRCS_MACOSX
  cefsimple_mac.mm
  simple_handler_mac.mm
  )
set(CEFSIMPLE_SRCS_WINDOWS
  cefsimple.exe.manifest
  cefsimple.rc
  cefsimple_win.cc
  resource.h
  simple_handler_win.cc
  )
APPEND_PLATFORM_SOURCES(CEFSIMPLE_SRCS)
source_group(cefsimple FILES ${CEFSIMPLE_SRCS})

set(CEFSIMPLE_RES_SRCS_WINDOWS
  res/cefsimple.ico
  res/small.ico
  )
APPEND_PLATFORM_SOURCES(CEFSIMPLE_RES_SRCS)
source_group(cefsimple\\\\res FILES ${CEFSIMPLE_RES_SRCS})

set(CEFSIMPLE_SRCS
  ${CEFSIMPLE_SRCS}
  ${CEFSIMPLE_RES_SRCS}
  )

# cefsimple helper sources.
#### Tell the build program to include helper_app.cc and helper_app.h during the build process
set(CEFSIMPLE_HELPER_SRCS_MACOSX
  process_helper_mac.cc
  helper_app.cc
  helper_app.h
  )
APPEND_PLATFORM_SOURCES(CEFSIMPLE_HELPER_SRCS)
source_group(cefsimple FILES ${CEFSIMPLE_HELPER_SRCS})

# cefsimple resources.
set(CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_SRCS_MACOSX
  mac/Info.plist
  mac/cefsimple.icns
  )
APPEND_PLATFORM_SOURCES(CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_SRCS)
source_group(cefsimple\\\\mac FILES ${CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_SRCS})

set(CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_ENGLISH_LPROJ_SRCS_MACOSX
  mac/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
  mac/English.lproj/MainMenu.xib
  )
APPEND_PLATFORM_SOURCES(CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_ENGLISH_LPROJ_SRCS)
source_group(cefsimple\\\\mac\\\\English.lproj FILES ${CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_ENGLISH_LPROJ_SRCS})

set(CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_SRCS
  ${CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_SRCS}
  ${CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_MAC_ENGLISH_LPROJ_SRCS}
  )


#
# Shared configuration.
#

# Target executable names.
set(CEF_TARGET "cefsimple")
if(OS_MACOSX)
  set(CEF_HELPER_TARGET "cefsimple_Helper")
  set(CEF_HELPER_OUTPUT_NAME "cefsimple Helper")
else()
  # Logical target used to link the libcef library.
  ADD_LOGICAL_TARGET("libcef_lib" "${CEF_LIB_DEBUG}" "${CEF_LIB_RELEASE}")
endif()

# Determine the target output directory.
SET_CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR()


#
# Linux configuration.
#

if(OS_LINUX)
  # Executable target.
  add_executable(${CEF_TARGET} ${CEFSIMPLE_SRCS})
  SET_EXECUTABLE_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${CEF_TARGET})
  add_dependencies(${CEF_TARGET} libcef_dll_wrapper)
  target_link_libraries(${CEF_TARGET} libcef_lib libcef_dll_wrapper ${CEF_STANDARD_LIBS})

  # Set rpath so that libraries can be placed next to the executable.
  set_target_properties(${CEF_TARGET} PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
  set_target_properties(${CEF_TARGET} PROPERTIES BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
  set_target_properties(${CEF_TARGET} PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR})

  # Copy binary and resource files to the target output directory.
  COPY_FILES("${CEF_TARGET}" "${CEF_BINARY_FILES}" "${CEF_BINARY_DIR}" "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}")
  COPY_FILES("${CEF_TARGET}" "${CEF_RESOURCE_FILES}" "${CEF_RESOURCE_DIR}" "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}")
  if (EXISTS "${CEF_BINARY_DIR}/libminigbm.so")
    COPY_FILES("${CEF_TARGET}" "libminigbm.so" "${CEF_BINARY_DIR}" "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}")
  endif()

  # Set SUID permissions on the chrome-sandbox target.
  SET_LINUX_SUID_PERMISSIONS("${CEF_TARGET}" "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}/chrome-sandbox")
endif()


#
# Mac OS X configuration.
#

if(OS_MACOSX)
  option(OPTION_USE_ARC "Build with ARC (automatic Reference Counting) on macOS." ON)
  if(OPTION_USE_ARC)
    list(APPEND CEF_COMPILER_FLAGS
      -fobjc-arc
      )
    set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES
      CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC "YES"
      )
  endif()

  # Output paths for the app bundles.
  set(CEF_APP "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}/${CEF_TARGET}.app")
  set(CEF_HELPER_APP "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}/${CEF_HELPER_OUTPUT_NAME}.app")

  # Variable referenced from Info.plist files.
  set(PRODUCT_NAME "${CEF_TARGET}")

  # Helper executable target.
  add_executable(${CEF_HELPER_TARGET} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${CEFSIMPLE_HELPER_SRCS})
  SET_EXECUTABLE_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${CEF_HELPER_TARGET})
  add_dependencies(${CEF_HELPER_TARGET} libcef_dll_wrapper)
  target_link_libraries(${CEF_HELPER_TARGET} libcef_dll_wrapper ${CEF_STANDARD_LIBS})
  set_target_properties(${CEF_HELPER_TARGET} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mac/helper-Info.plist
    OUTPUT_NAME ${CEF_HELPER_OUTPUT_NAME}
    )

  if(USE_SANDBOX)
    # Logical target used to link the cef_sandbox library.
    ADD_LOGICAL_TARGET("cef_sandbox_lib" "${CEF_SANDBOX_LIB_DEBUG}" "${CEF_SANDBOX_LIB_RELEASE}")
    target_link_libraries(${CEF_HELPER_TARGET} cef_sandbox_lib)
  endif()

  # Main executable target.
  add_executable(${CEF_TARGET} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_SRCS} ${CEFSIMPLE_SRCS})
  SET_EXECUTABLE_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${CEF_TARGET})
  add_dependencies(${CEF_TARGET} libcef_dll_wrapper "${CEF_HELPER_TARGET}")
  target_link_libraries(${CEF_TARGET} libcef_dll_wrapper ${CEF_STANDARD_LIBS})
  set_target_properties(${CEF_TARGET} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mac/Info.plist
    )

  # Copy files into the main app bundle.
  add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${CEF_TARGET}
    POST_BUILD
    # Copy the helper app bundle into the Frameworks directory.
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
            "${CEF_HELPER_APP}"
            "${CEF_APP}/Contents/Frameworks/${CEF_HELPER_OUTPUT_NAME}.app"
    # Copy the CEF framework into the Frameworks directory.
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
            "${CEF_BINARY_DIR}/Chromium Embedded Framework.framework"
            "${CEF_APP}/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium Embedded Framework.framework"
    VERBATIM
    )

  # Manually process and copy over resource files.
  # The Xcode generator can support this via the set_target_properties RESOURCE
  # directive but that doesn't properly handle nested resource directories.
  # Remove these prefixes from input file paths.
  set(PREFIXES "mac/")
  COPY_MACOSX_RESOURCES("${CEFSIMPLE_RESOURCES_SRCS}" "${PREFIXES}" "${CEF_TARGET}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${CEF_APP}")
endif()


#
# Windows configuration.
#

if(OS_WINDOWS)
  # Executable target.
  add_executable(${CEF_TARGET} WIN32 ${CEFSIMPLE_SRCS})
  add_dependencies(${CEF_TARGET} libcef_dll_wrapper)
  SET_EXECUTABLE_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${CEF_TARGET})
  target_link_libraries(${CEF_TARGET} libcef_lib libcef_dll_wrapper ${CEF_STANDARD_LIBS})

  if(USE_SANDBOX)
    # Logical target used to link the cef_sandbox library.
    ADD_LOGICAL_TARGET("cef_sandbox_lib" "${CEF_SANDBOX_LIB_DEBUG}" "${CEF_SANDBOX_LIB_RELEASE}")
    target_link_libraries(${CEF_TARGET} cef_sandbox_lib ${CEF_SANDBOX_STANDARD_LIBS})
  endif()

  # Add the custom manifest files to the executable.
  ADD_WINDOWS_MANIFEST("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${CEF_TARGET}" "exe")

  # Copy binary and resource files to the target output directory.
  COPY_FILES("${CEF_TARGET}" "${CEF_BINARY_FILES}" "${CEF_BINARY_DIR}" "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}")
  COPY_FILES("${CEF_TARGET}" "${CEF_RESOURCE_FILES}" "${CEF_RESOURCE_DIR}" "${CEF_TARGET_OUT_DIR}")
endif()
```